# How to dynamically set position of elements using .offset() or .position()

Tags: jquery, css, position, css-position, offset

I am trying to set the position of two divs to the very top and the very bottom of a table cell, so that they can be selected for a resizing function. However, part of my application involves the user spanning rows of the table (as depicted in the snippet). Is it possible to dynamically set the positions of the resize divs (north & south) to the top and bottom of a table cell, respectively? That way when the user spans rows of the table, the resize divs will move with the borders.

Can this be done using .offset() or .position()? I'm not sure which would be the right approach. I don't think this can be done with CSS alone. But if anyone can prove me wrong I'm open to suggestions.

```js
$('.appt-text').before("<div class='resize-north'></div>");
$('.appt-text').after("<div class='resize-south'></div>");
$('td').attr("align", "center");

$('.resize-south').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).css('cursor', 's-resize');
});

$('.resize-north').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).css('cursor', 'n-resize');
});
```

```css
.resize-north {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.resize-south {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

/* CSS code from here down is just for visualization */

.appt-text {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

td {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

td div {
  max-width: 150px;
  outline: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  border-top: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-left: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

tr td, th {
  border-right: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
}

th {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr class="days-of-the-week">
              <th scope="col"></th>
              <th scope="col">A</th>
              <th scope="col">B</th>
              <th scope="col">C</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="rowHdr">1</th>
              <td class="cell" rowspan="2"><div contenteditable="true" class="appt-text"></div></td>
              <td class="cell"><div contenteditable="true" class="appt-text"></div></td>
              <td class="cell"><div contenteditable="true" class="appt-text"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="rowHdr">2</th>
              <td class="cell"><div contenteditable="true" class="appt-text"></div></td>
              <td class="cell"><div contenteditable="true" class="appt-text"></div></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `.offset()` gets the position relative to the whole document. `.position()` gets the position relative to the parent. `.offset()` can be used to get or set the position, `.position()` can only be used to get the position.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `position: absolute` and `top: 0px;` or `bottom: 0px;`. These should work as long as the containing element is also a positioned one.

You can do that by setting the parent/container/ancestor element to `position: relative`. It won't change position itself relative to what it was before, but it now counts as a positioned element in which `position: absolute` elements can be positioned.

Below is the slightly modified CSS with those changes made. It should get you a little closer to what you described.

```
.resize-north {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;  /*<--*/
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px; /*<--*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.resize-south {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute; /*<--*/
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0px; /*<--*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/* CSS code from here down is just for visualization */

.appt-text {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative; /*<--*/
}

td {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; /*<--*/
}

td div {
  max-width: 150px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative; /*<--*/
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  border-top: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-left: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative; /*<--*/
}

tr td,
th {
  border-right: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
}

th {
  width: 80px;
}
```

Hope this helps or at least pushes you in the right direction... You may also want to look into [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), though you may have already ruled that out.

Comment: `absolute` positioning is unfortunately not an option for me in my case, even if I could get them correctly positioned, their position would have to change with the rowspan set by the user.

Comment: Alright, I understand. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. Good luck!